Showing different picklist values dynamic in different rows of a table LWC
I want to use a combobox in an HTML table in LWC component.
<template for:each={recordsToDisplay} for:item="asset" for:index="index">
                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps" key={asset.id}>
                    <td class="slds-truncate"> <a data-attrival={asset.assetId} onclick={handleLinkClick}>{asset.assetName}</a> </td>
                    <td class="slds-truncate">{asset.serialNumber}</td>
                    <td class="slds-truncate">{asset.tag}</td>
                    <td class="slds-truncate">{asset.orderCode}</td>
                    <td class="slds-truncate">
                            <lightning-combobox
                                        name="progress"
                                        lvariant="label-hidden"
                                        value={value}
                                        placeholder="Select Classification"
                                        options={classifications}
                                        onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>
                        </td> <---- Dynamic values in this picklist--> </tr></template>

Now for each Asset, classification needs to be calculated in Apex that I can do.
However, I am not sure how to show different picklist values in different rows in the lightning-combobox ?
Any suggestions would be helpful

Check this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4XxNSAV

You need to ensure that each row has its own set of options. You can achieve this by dynamically setting the options for each combobox based on the asset data.
For example your code looks like as below:
Apex class:
public with sharing class AssetController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<AssetWrapper> getAssetsWithClassifications() {
        List<AssetWrapper> listOfAssets = new List<AssetWrapper>();
        // Query your assets and classifications here
        for (Asset__c asset : [SELECT Id, Name, SerialNumber__c, Tag__c, OrderCode__c FROM Asset__c]) {
            List<SelectOption> classifications = new List<SelectOption>();
            // Add your logic to populate classifications
            classifications.add(new SelectOption('Option1', 'Option 1'));
            classifications.add(new SelectOption('Option2', 'Option 2'));
            listOfAssets.add(new AssetWrapper(asset, classifications));
        }
        return listOfAssets;
    }

    public class AssetWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled public Asset__c asset { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public List<SelectOption> classifications { get; set; }

        public AssetWrapper(Asset__c asset, List<SelectOption> classifications) {
            this.asset = asset;
            this.classifications = classifications;
        }
    }
}

JS:
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAssetsWithClassifications from '@salesforce/apex/AssetController.getAssetsWithClassifications';

export default class AssetTable extends LightningElement {
    @track recordsToDisplay = [];

    @wire(getAssetsWithClassifications)
    wiredAssets({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.recordsToDisplay = data.map(assetWrapper => ({
                id: assetWrapper.asset.Id,
                assetName: assetWrapper.asset.Name,
                serialNumber: assetWrapper.asset.SerialNumber__c,
                tag: assetWrapper.asset.Tag__c,
                orderCode: assetWrapper.asset.OrderCode__c,
                classifications: assetWrapper.classifications,
                selectedClassification: '' // Default value
            }));
        } else if (error) {
        // Handle error
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const assetId = event.target.dataset.id;
        const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
        this.recordsToDisplay = this.recordsToDisplay.map(asset => {
        if (asset.id === assetId) {
            return { ...asset, selectedClassification: selectedValue };
        }
            return asset;
        });
    }
}

HTML:
<template for:each={recordsToDisplay} for:item="asset" for:index="index">
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps" key={asset.id}>
        <td class="slds-truncate">
            <a data-attrival={asset.assetId} onclick={handleLinkClick}>{asset.assetName}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="slds-truncate">{asset.serialNumber}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate">{asset.tag}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate">{asset.orderCode}</td>
        <td class="slds-truncate">
            <lightning-combobox
                name="progress"
                label="Classification"
                value={asset.selectedClassification}
                placeholder="Select Classification"
                options={asset.classifications}
                data-id={asset.id}
                onchange={handleChange}>
            </lightning-combobox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>


Thanks Tushar. I actually ended up using this same method for dynamic options
